# ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00923

I am trying to concatenate some fields to return a single string for each row from an oracle table.  This is in 10g.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT t.value || '|' || t.label || '|' t.label_abbrv || '||' "mylist" 
  FROM list_value t
 WHERE t.value BETWEEN 195001 AND 195300;
```

I'm getting the "FROM keyword not found where expected" error.  This is really annoying.  It's a simple query.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh!  I found the problem.  I'm missing a concat!

```
SELECT value || '|' || label || '|' ****||**** label_abbrv || '||' "mylist"
from list_value where (value between 195001 and 195300);
```

Comment: The "mylist" might be a problem too... but I suspect you didn't mean it literally.  If you replaced it with 'bananas|apples|sofas', then no problems.

Comment: I suppose "mylist" is a column alias ;)

Comment: @jhartelt:  yes, "mylist" is just the column header;  I fixed where the missing pipes were...I couldn't copy/paste as the query is on a different network/computer

Answer (score 2):

If you used SQLPLUS client, it would have saved you a little time:

```
SQL> SELECT value || '|' || label || '|' label_abbrv || '||' "mylist"
  2  from list_value where (value between 195001 and 195300);
SELECT value || '|' || label || '|' label_abbrv || '||' "mylist"
                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

You can break up your query to multiple lines to isolate the problem:

```
SQL> edit
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT value || '|'
  2  || label ||
  3  '|' label_abbrv ||
  4  '||' "mylist"
  5  from list_value
  6  where
  7* (value between 195001 and 195300)
SQL> /
'|' label_abbrv ||
                *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

You might find SQLPLUS to be "primitive," but, hmmm, that's good for another question.  Let me see if anyone else has asked about it yet.

Comment: SQLPlus may be primitive but its the only tool that always works and never lies. (for the record I spend most my day in TOAD).  One up vote for the great answer.

Comment: @ericp:  great suggestion!  I'll have to try breaking up the query into multiple lines the next time it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer to your own question is still wrong - it should be:

```
SELECT value || '|' || label || '|' || label_abbrv || '||' "mylist" 
                                   ^^^^
```